# Table value as function parameter lua

Tags: javascript, lua, roblox

Hello I am trying to pass a variable as a functions parameter and I am having problems when I am passing it through as a non variable ex `SetOption(optionTable[1])` works just fine but I want it to conditionally pass through a different value from the table.
Current Attempt:

```
SetOption(option)

if x then
getgenv().option = optionTable[1]
end
if y then
getgenv().option = optionTable[2]
end
if z then
getgenv().option = optionTable[3]
end
```

But in return it only returns the first value from the table. Any idea on how I can properly achieve what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Hi Dear, you are calling getter inside the function (GETGENV) i thing you need to call the setter (SETGENV). Also, your syntax is like BASH i Prefer to use JavaScript syntax like. if (option == 'x') {  theFunctionToCall()}

Comment: `But in return it only returns the first value from the table` - Your code returns nothing: there is no `return` statement there.  So, how do you check the correctness of your code?